# How to avoid overlapping of fixed div's in print as pdf?

Tags: jquery, css, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have a div which I have fixed for my web page

```
.header-logo{
     width:100%; 
height:55px; 
position:fixed; 
z-index:100;
   }
```

I have used a plugin and when I click on "print as PDF" the div's which I have fixed are overlapping somewhere else  on the other divs. How to make the div's fixed in print as pdf

Answer (score 1):

Add `print-padding` class to the content block which comes after repititive header.

```
.header-logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}
.print-top-padding {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

You can do the same for footer tag by adding margin-bottom.
The margin can be given as per the height of fix header or footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @media print{
       .header-logo{
         width:100%; 
         height:55px; 
         position:fixed; 
        z-index:100;
        display:block;
      }
    }

    function printDetail() {
    window.print();
}
     <button onclick="printDetail()">print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a stylesheet with your custom style for printing using `media="print"` as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourpath/print.css" media="print"/>
```

or

embed styles as in html using media query

Try to `position` the body `relative` and the `.header-logo` `fixed`:

```
<style>
@media print {
   body {
        position: relative;
     }
     .header-logo {
        width:100%; 
        height:55px; 
        position:fixed; 
        z-index:100;
        display:block;
     }
}
</style>
```

or

embed styles as in html using `<style>` tag

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body {
        position: relative;
     }
     .header-logo {
        width:100%; 
        height:55px; 
        position:fixed; 
        z-index:100;
        display:block;
     }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Method to implement header footer properly in pdf*

After finding a lot on internet on different solutions and workaround, I finally sharing a way that works for me.

Please Add these style to container (the div in which report is rendered)

```html
     <div #scrollingContainer class="col-xxs-9 content-container" style="overflow-x: hidden;width:100%;">
     </div>
```

Div properties may differ

Wrap the component  into the table structure with thead and tfoot according to the size of your header and footer(table is wrapped inside a div)

```html
    <div style="width: 100%;">
                <table style="table-layout: fixed;
                width: 100%;"> // Add this css to make main table fixed, child tables will still scroll
                    <thead class="page-break-before">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="height: 80px;"></div> // space for the respective header
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                              <div> Your Data Goes Here........</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot class="show-in-print page-break-after">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="height: 130px;"></div> // space for the respective footer
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Sample Header and footer

```html
      <div class="page-break-before header">
        <div>A long header content...</div>
      </div>

  
      <div class=" page-break-after footer">
        <p> A long footer content...</p>
      </div>
```

```css
    .header {
     position : fixed;
     top: 0px;

     }

    .footer {
     position : fixed;
     bottom: 0px;

     }
```